# PNP-JS Create File from File Lib template

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I need to create/add a new File from Files Lib, then i need to set the name of the file with an unique ID and update other fieds. I can update the fields without any problems, but i couldn't find a way to create the file.

How can i possibly achieve the New => Create from template like in the image below

[image]

I've tried many ways but nothing fullfill my request.

## 1

this.web.lists.getByTitle('myFilesLib').items.add() => i get an error about the need to use SPFileCollection.Add()

## 2

this.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(url).files.addTemplateFile => there is nothing for custom template

## 3

this.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(url).files.add => i need to provide a file.

Answer (score 0):

1. For JSOM, you can try this:

   newFile = parentList.get_rootFolder().get_files().add(fileCreateInfo);

For CSOM:

```
var creationInformation = new ListItemCreationInformation();
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem listItem = list.AddItem(creationInformation);
listItem.FieldValues["Foo"] = "Bar";
listItem.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Some wiki for this way: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37575.sharepoint-online-working-with-files-inside-document-library-using-jsom.aspx

2. this.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(url).files.addTemplateFile is used to add page, so it is not suitable for your scenario.

http://www.ktskumar.com/2016/08/pnp-js-core-create-new-page-sharepoint-library/

3. The PnP JS method requires a File DOM or BLOB object for uploading a file to the SharePoint. Based on the those, we will try two options to upload a file to the SharePoint Library or folder in a library:BLOB/FileAPI
   http://www.ktskumar.com/2016/09/pnp-js-core-upload-file-sharepoint/

More reference for you from Microsoft:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx

Comment: nothing you reference is about PNP-JS and Template/Content-Type. I cannot use JSOM and CSOM is for C#. The link about PNP-JS is about creating SharePoint Page that is not the question i've asked! But thanks for your times

Comment: I am not familar with the Template/Content-Type in PnpJs. But the reference I provided in the way 3 is for uploading files in PnpJS. You question description contains 3 way, so I answered them one by one. Please check again. For the Template/Content-Type issue, I need to research it tomorrow.

Comment: In the way 3, you comment you need to provide a file, the solution for providing the file is FileDom/BLOB.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code to use when you want to upload an existing ContentType to your content library on SharePoint.

```
const templateUrl = '/sites/App/Template/Forms/Template/test.docx'
const name = 'test.docx'
const depositUrl = '/sites/App/Template'

const web = new Web('http://localhost:8080/sites/App');   // Proxy URL for Dev
web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(templateUrl)
    .getBuffer()
    .then((templateData: ArrayBuffer) => { 
        web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(depositUrl).files.add(name, templateData)); 
});
```

There is an issue if you use SP-Rest-Proxy at the moment (file is corrupted on SharePoint) but it should be fix soon.

If you Deploy your app on SharePoint, it work as expected.

## Related links:

https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/issues/196#issuecomment-410908170

https://github.com/koltyakov/sp-rest-proxy/issues/61